# R Find nearest zipcode between Two US Zipcode columns

Tags: r

I have two lists of zip codes and want to pick the nearest zip code from second list against my first list.e.g.30043 (from second list) is closest to the zip code 30094 (from first list).So,it should come against 30094.The code should compare the distance from each zip and pick the nearest one.Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: There is an R package, "ZipRadius" that may help. Also the archived package "zipcode" can provide a list of lat/long for each zip code